# How to count subprocesses that reached certain state

Tags: bash, shell-script, function

I have a bash script that launches >20 subprocesses (functions launched with `&` in background) and want to include a progress indicator that tells the user how many of those subprocesses are already running.

The problem is that those subprocesses need quite some time to boot up (~20 seconds, depending on the network). Is there a way that I could count the number of subprocesses that have already successfully booted?

I can put any code into the bash function which will be run when the subprocess is ready. However I don't know a good way to increment the global variable which is holding the amount of jobs that are ready.

Comment: How you do you even tell if a job is done "booting up"? You can try looking at the output of `jobs` and take it from there.

Comment: I can add any code into the job. The job itself is aware of its bootup process, so setting a global variable or pushing something into a pipe is no problem.

Comment: The previous comment is a bit poorly worded. I can put any code into the bash function which will be run when the subprocess is ready. However I don't know a good way to increment the global variable which is holding the amount of jobs that are ready.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external file as your global variable. Here's an example.

```
file="$(mktemp)"
f() { sleep 3; echo x; sleep 3; }
for i in {1..10} ; do
    >>"$file" f &
done

switch=true
while $switch; do
    sleep 1
    cnt=$(wc -l "$file")
    cnt="${cnt%%${file}}"    #this is needed to remove the file name
                             #from the output of wc -l
    echo "$cnt"
    [ "$cnt" -ge 5 ] && switch=false
done
rm "$file"
```

Saving this to `example` and sourcing gives this:

```
$ . example
0
0
10
```

Once you have access to

```
cnt=$(wc -l "$file")
cnt="${cnt%%${file}}"
```

it's easy to rework this code into a progress bar.

Don't forget to adjust the eternal loop breaker `[ "$cnt" -ge 5 ] && switch=false` to your situation.